# C# Visual Studio thinks my class ends before it does

Tags: c#

I have a normal class with no errors, but visual studio thinks the class ends before it should. It thinks the c* bracket of the whole class itself. Can you help me? I will show you a photo of what I mean:

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can see what I mean with the picture: the class ends where it shouldn't. I have already tried erasing a adding new brackets, copy and paste, and almost anything you can think of.

EDIT:

```html
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using LukeWaffel.BUI;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Pattern : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text levelTxt;
    public GameObject[] displayRow;
    //a messageBox instance that can be used many times
    private UIBox box;
    public GameObject displayPrefab;
    public GameObject displayBlockParent;
    public GameObject userPrefab;
    public GameObject userBlockParent;
    public GameObject[] userRow;
    //an array that is used for a function to check if all boolians in the array are true
    private bool[] alltrue;
    public int zNum;
    public int xNum;
    public int yNum;
    private Color[] colors;
    private bool isHardGenerate = false;
    //the space between blocks needed to create a table
    private float offset;
    //how many colors are currently at play for exapmle: colorNum = 2 (the colors allowed in a pattern are red and yellow)
    private int colorNum = 2;
    // a variable that indicates the amount of colored blocks in a pattern
    private int numToColor = 0;
    public static int level = 0;
    // a class that indicates which blocks are active: user or display;
    private BlockController b;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        levelTxt.text = "Level: " + (level + 1);
        //initialize the colors available in the current game.
        List<Color> colorsTemp = new List<Color>();
        colorsTemp.Add(Color.red);
        colorsTemp.Add(Color.yellow);
        colorsTemp.Add(Color.green);
        //convert the colors to array. the list was there just to add the colors hence thte name colorsTemp
        colors = colorsTemp.ToArray<Color>();
        //the blockController class controls how much time the user has to see the pattern before it is drawn
        b = gameObject.GetComponent<BlockController>();
        offset = 1f;
        //start to generate the pattern
        GenerateEasy();
    }
    private void GenerateEasy()
    { 
        //set the number of colored blocks(randomized) GetRandomFloat is a custom function created to decide the skip of the randomized number. By defult that value is 0.5f
        private float rnd = GetRandomFloat(1, 4);
        if(rnd == 1)//that means that all blocks would be colored and thats an easy pattern. because of that we need to change the number
        {
            rnd++;
        }
//the formula to decide how many blocks will be colored
numToColor = Mathf.CeilToInt((Num* xNum * yNum)/rnd);
        // Create empty grid
        displayRow = new GameObject[zNum * xNum * yNum];
        userRow = new GameObject[zNum * xNum * yNum];
        alltrue = new bool[yNum * xNum * zNum];
        // Create blocks
        for (int i = 0; i<yNum; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<xNum; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k<zNum; k++)
                {
                    //creating display table we are not selecting the pattern yet.
                    GameObject g = Instantiate(displayPrefab, new Vector3(j * offset, i * offset, k * offset), Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0), displayBlockParent.transform);
displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = g;
                    //creating the coloring table (in all variables named build/user)
                    GameObject o = Instantiate(userPrefab, new Vector3(j * offset, i * offset, k * offset), Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0), userBlockParent.transform);
userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = o;
                    userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[0];





        }







            }
     }
        //reverse the array because by defult the blocks are upside down, so we need to correct that and flip all the blocks again
        Array.Reverse(displayRow);
        Array.Reverse(userRow);
        //create pattern for the display table. notice in the for loop the outer for loop runs numToColor times, the amount of blocks that should be colored
        for (int s = 0; s<numToColor; s++)
        {
            //the for loop runs once too much, so in the first loop we need to not make any actions, unless num to color is 1, and then it only runs one time.
            if (numToColor != 1 && s == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            //initialize the colored and notcolored lists. this only exists in generateEasy because this makes the pattern easier to remember. colored are the blocks that are not good for coloring and not colored are the blocks viable to color.
            List<GameObject> colored = new List<GameObject>();
List<GameObject> notColored = new List<GameObject>();
            //if non of the blocks are colored yet, color a block randomly
            if (displayRow.ToList<GameObject>().All(p => p.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[0]))
            {
                int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, yNum * xNum * zNum);
displayRow[randomIndex].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, colorNum)];
            }

            //this for checks if any of the blocks that exist contain a color that isn't red(the defult color)
            for (int i = 0; i<yNum; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<xNum; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k<zNum; k++)
                    {
                        //the colors array are all the available colors in the game. because red is the defult color and the first one in the array, it does not count as a colored block and therefor need to be skipped for the if statment.
                        if (colors.Skip(1).Any(p => p == displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color))
                        {
                            //adding the colored blocks to the colored array, which helps later for the formula for the easy pattern, and at the same time making them unable to be recolored accidently by the pattern.
                            colored.Add(displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //thia doe loop checks if the block that's not already colored is viable for being colored for the easy level. if it is, it adds the block to the notColored array
            for (int i = 0; i<yNum; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<xNum; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k<zNum; k++)
                    {
                        if (displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[0] && (colored.Any(p => (j != xNum - 1 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + (j + 1) * zNum + k]))
                              || (j != 0 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + (j - 1) * zNum + k]))
                              || (i != 0 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, displayRow[(i - 1) * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]))
                              || (i != yNum - 1 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, displayRow[(i + 1) * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]))
                              || (k != 0 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k - 1]))
                              || (k != zNum - 1 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k + 1])))))
                        {
                            notColored.Add(displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            //finally, one of the not colored blocks in the not colored array is randomly colored with a random color according to level.
            notColored.ToArray()[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, notColored.ToArray().Length)].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, colorNum)];

        }
    }

    private void GenerateHard()
{
    //up until the very end, Generate hard is extremley similar to easyGenerate. if you want detailed comment on most of the function, please refer to easy generate.
    //set the number of colored blocks
    float rnd = GetRandomFloat(1, 4);
    if (rnd == 1)
    {
        rnd++;
    }
    numToColor = Mathf.CeilToInt((zNum * xNum * yNum) / rnd);
    displayRow = new GameObject[zNum * xNum * yNum];
    userRow = new GameObject[zNum * xNum * yNum];
    alltrue = new bool[yNum * xNum * zNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
            {
                GameObject g = Instantiate(displayPrefab, new Vector3(j * offset, i * offset, k * offset), Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0), displayBlockParent.transform);
                displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = g;
                GameObject o = Instantiate(userPrefab, new Vector3(j * offset, i * offset, k * offset), Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0), userBlockParent.transform);
                userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = o;
                userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[0];

            }

        }
    }
    Array.Reverse(displayRow);
    Array.Reverse(userRow);
    //create a pattern. for now it is the same as easy generate but it's going to get different soon.
    for (int s = 1; s < numToColor; s++)
    {
        List<GameObject> colored = new List<GameObject>();
        List<GameObject> notColored = new List<GameObject>();
        if (displayRow.ToList<GameObject>().All(p => p.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[0]))
        {
            int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, yNum * xNum * zNum);
            displayRow[randomIndex].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, colorNum)];

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
                {
                    if (colors.Skip(1).Any(p => p == displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color))
                    {
                        colored.Add(displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //now is the different part, the for loop does not check if the block will be viable for an easy pattern, it just adds every blocks that's not colored, even if that block makes the pattern much harder
        for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
                {
                    if (displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[0])
                    {
                        notColored.Add(displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //like before, the progranm chooses to color a block in the not coloed array randomly.
        notColored.ToArray()[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, notColored.ToArray().Length)].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, colorNum)];

    }


}
// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    //this huge outer if is resposible for cheking the pattern
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && !CrossHair.ok)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
                {
                    //checks if the pattern is exactly equal to what the user has colored
                    if (displayRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color.Equals(userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color))
                    {
                        alltrue[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alltrue[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //if the user got the pattern right then...
        if (alltrue.ToList<bool>().All(b => b))
        {
            if ((level + 1) % 10 != 0 && level + 1 != 0)
            {
                //make the mouse appear and make the user unable to move the player or color any blocks so that the user can focus on the messegebox
                CrossHair.ok = true;
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
                Cursor.visible = true;
                //display the message bix
                box = new UIBox("bID", BUI.UIType.Message);
                box.header = "You have passed the level!";
                box.body = "You have passed this current level. Have you got what it takes to take on the next Puzzle?";
                box.buttons.Add(new UIButton("Yes, next level!", FuncButton));
                BUI.Instance.AddToQueue(box);
                //reset everything for the next level. also increases the level.
                b.Reset();
                level++;
                levelTxt.text = "Level: " + (level + 1);
                DestroyArray(userRow);
                DestroyArray(displayRow);
                //generate hard and generate easy switch turns.
                if (!isHardGenerate)
                {
                    yNum++;
                    isHardGenerate = true;
                    GenerateHard();

                }
                else
                {
                    isHardGenerate = false;
                    xNum++;
                    GenerateEasy();
                }
            }
            //every 10 levels a color is added to the table.
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("passed level 10");
                CrossHair.ok = true;
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
                Cursor.visible = true;
                box = new UIBox("bID", BUI.UIType.Message);
                box.header = "You have passed the level!";
                box.body = "You have passed this current level. Have you got what it takes to take on the next Puzzle?";
                box.buttons.Add(new UIButton("Yes, next level!", FuncButton));
                BUI.Instance.AddToQueue(box);
                xNum = 2;
                yNum = 2;
                colorNum++;
                b.Reset();
                level++;
                levelTxt.text = "Level: " + (level + 1);
                DestroyArray(userRow);
                DestroyArray(displayRow);
                isHardGenerate = false;

                GenerateEasy();

            }
        }
        //if the user lost then...  
        else
        {
            //for this refer to the beginning of the if statment
            CrossHair.ok = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            Cursor.visible = true;
            box = new UIBox("bID", BUI.UIType.Message);
            box.header = "You have failed";
            box.body = "You have failed this current level. Have you got what it takes to try again?";
            box.buttons.Add(new UIButton("Yes, try this level again!", FuncButton));
            BUI.Instance.AddToQueue(box);
            //if level doesnt equal to 0, go down a levle, you cant go down from the first level.
            if (level != 0)
                level--;
            b.Reset();
            levelTxt.text = "Level: " + (level + 1);
            DestroyArray(userRow);
            DestroyArray(displayRow);

            if (isHardGenerate)
            {
                yNum--;
                isHardGenerate = false;
                GenerateEasy();
            }
            else
            {
                if (level != 0)
                {
                    isHardGenerate = true;
                    xNum--;

                    GenerateHard();
                }
                else
                {

                    GenerateEasy();
                }

            }
        }
        //destroys every onject in an array
        void DestroyArray(GameObject[] b)
        {
            foreach (GameObject k in b)
                Destroy(k.gameObject);

        }
        //lets the player move again and cloles the message box
        void FuncButton(UIBox boxInfo, UIButton buttonInfo)
        {

            CrossHair.ok = false;
            BUI.Instance.CloseBox(box.id);
        }
    }
}
//go to refrence to find the meaning of the function. (in easyGenerate.)
public float GetRandomFloat(int min, int max, float value = 0.5f)
{
    int multipliedMin = (int)(min / value);
    int multipliedMax = (int)(max / value);

    return ((float)UnityEngine.Random.Range(multipliedMin, multipliedMax)) * value;
}
}
```

Comment: Please add your actual code to the question *as text*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `private` in `private float rnd = GetRandomFloat(1, 4);`

Take a look at the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) in order to understand the access modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a property inside a method. These should go within the initial class braces.

Comment: It doesn't look like a property.